# Bluetooth adapter can't be found after the latest upgrade of Raspbian

Tags: apt, raspbian-buster, update, lxde, lxpanel

After the latest upgrade of Raspbian buster everything seems to be falling down. Softwares are crashing. And bluetooth adapter is missing. Also the bluetooth menu is missing. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: restore your most recent backup before the upgrade

Comment: There was no backup I am afraid.

Comment: Make a new installation of the Raspberry Pi OS. Use a new SD Card. Check your power supply.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the upgrade went though successfully? Try running `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get -f install` and make sure they don't report any errors.

Next, I'd check if you can get a USB BT adapter working (if you have one). That would tell you where to look next.

If none of your adapters work, you're likely having trouble with the BT software stack. Check the status and logs of `bluetooth` and `bluealsa` services.

If USB BT adapters work but the built-in doesn't, it's likely a problem in the hardware configuration. Check that BT is enabled in `config.txt` and there are no conflicting settings. Have a look in the kernel log (`dmesg`) for evidence that the BT hardware is detected and the driver is found and loaded. Then look for any error messages from `hciuart` service.

Comment: I tried everything. But couldn't fix anything. Again flashed with the new Raspbian.

Comment: If BT doesn't work after a system reinstall, I would start to suspect a hardware issue. Can you check your Pi with an [older Raspbian release](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/)?

Comment: Already a new reinstall of OS fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README. I appended to the config.txt

```
dtoverlay=miniuart-bt,krnbt=on
```

This prioritized the bluetooth reception for serial communication over the GPIOs 14 & 15 and solved my issue with the Adapter not found error.