# How do I fix my crashed bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, uart, systemd

After an apt update today, my bluetooth menu disappeared from the menu bar. Even the services are not running anymore. Whenever I am trying to fix something(with systemctl and apt), this message appears:

```
Job for hciuart.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status hciuart.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

What should I do now?
Is there any way to reinstall this?

This is a different question than previous which is recognized duplicate. But two problems are very different from each other.

Comment: restore your most recent backup before the upgrade

Comment: oh ... wait ... https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113543/bluetooth-adapter-cant-be-found-after-the-latest-upgrade-of-raspbian ... why are you asking AGAIN?

Comment: @JaromandaX two things are different. One is for software side and another is for hardware side problem.

Comment: Duplicate question: [Bluetooth adapter can't be found after the latest upgrade of Raspbian](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/113543/bluetooth-adapter-cant-be-found-after-the-latest-upgrade-of-raspbian)